# Namespace issues when implementing mediator.js

Tags: php, css, doctype, xml-namespaces, mediator

I have a web page (php) which handles a series of ajax forms and simple js hide/show divs based on content from an external upload to be used by registered members of an organization.  In order to build a more maintainable and extendable site, I have been looking into using architectural patterns to prevent unending jQuery chaining; namely, the mediator pattern.

Has anyone used Jack Lawson's [Mediator.js](http://thejacklawson.com/Mediator.js/mediator.html)? Basically, you can Subscribe with the Mediator to listen on a "channel" (namespaces) with a function to be run when something is Published on that same channel (and even check a predicate true/false function before responding, if needed).

**The Goal:**
The mediator.js api seems like it has great potential as well as forcing me to implement a valid xhtml document and use namespaces correctly.  Implementing a mediator pattern seems like a great way to decouple the javascript code and make a complicated web-app much more maintainable and extendable in the future.

**The Frustration:** 
I believe I understand both namespaces and the mediator pattern as implemented by the mediator.js api.  I have been able to successfully publish DOM attribute events through a mediator on specific "channels" (namespaces) and Subscribe to those channels and react to them - even using the mediator.js method of testing a "predicate" on that channel in order to ascertain whether a response is necessary.  But my CSS is now incapable of recognizing elements due to the new namespaces.

I created namespaces like this:

```
<xmlns:active='http://www.xxx.com/tracks/active'  
xmlns:completed='http://www.xxx.com/tracks/completed'  
xmlns:inactive='http://www.xxx.com/tracks/inactive'>
```

and then applying them to html elements, like:

```
<active:div ...>stuff</active:div>
```

I changed the css file accordingly:

```
active|div {   css formatting }
```

Still, the page's css formatting is broken.

The doctype portion of the rendered page looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I am not entirely sure this isn't required, but I have tried adding:

```
<? header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>
```

Which produces an XML parsing error of:

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

which points to the equal sign in this namespace definition `xmlns:active='http://www.xxx.com/tracks/active'` as the problem, but every doc I read shows this as being correct syntax.

**Questions:**

1. Why is my CSS broken after implementing the namespaces I showed
   above?
2. Why, when I add the `<? header('Content-Type:
   application/xhtml+xml'); ?>` in the header, do I get the parsing error
   mentioned?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > Why is my CSS broken after implementing the namespaces I showed above?

   The namespaces can only be resolved within your CSS when you add `@namespace` declarations corresponding to your XML namespaces. This is described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-namespace/#declaration).

   Make sure your stylesheet has the following statement, placed at an appropriate location (directly after all `@charset`s and `@import`s):

   ```
   @namespace active 'http://www.xxx.com/tracks/active';
   ```

   If you have styles for the rest of your namespaces, you'll need to include those as well:

   ```
   @namespace completed 'http://www.xxx.com/tracks/completed';
   @namespace inactive 'http://www.xxx.com/tracks/inactive';
   ```
2. > Why, when I add the `<? header('Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml'); ?>` in the header, do I get the parsing error mentioned?

   This is because when you add the header, your XHTML page is served as an XML-serialized document. Incidentally, this is how XHTML pages are supposed to be served, as XHTML is derived from XML. If you don't include the header, servers will generally send them as `text/html` instead, which means your XHTML runs through an HTML tag soup parser and not an XML parser.

   XML parsing rules are *very strict*; a single syntax error will prevent your entire document from rendering. Since you appear to have a malformed `xmlns` declaration, that prevents your XHTML page from being rendered properly. On the other hand, given the flexibility and leniency of HTML syntax rules, a browser won't spit any error messages even if it encounters serious syntax problems in your markup — it'll just try to waltz its way through the errors and make guesses at what the intended DOM structure was.

   As for the error itself, your `xmlns` attributes look like they should be part of the opening `html` tag instead of their own element, since they are attributes:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
         xmlns:active="http://www.xxx.com/tracks/active"  
         xmlns:completed="http://www.xxx.com/tracks/completed"  
         xmlns:inactive="http://www.xxx.com/tracks/inactive">
   ```

   Lastly, *you need that header*! Without it, your XHTML won't be parsed The Way It Should Be™, and therefore your CSS namespaces won't work either.

Comment: This response was HUGELY helpful!  Thanks, BoltClock!  I forgot to mention I had done the @namespace declarations, but your corrections to the html element along with where to put it made the difference.  My code still needs further corrections but I don't think it will be too far off.  Is it best to step through these xml parsing errors one by one (if you believe you're not too far off),  Or is there a better way?  I seem to remember reading about xhtml validators not being perfect in themselves.  Do you have a favorite method you use?  **Thanks for the Big League help.**

Comment: No problem. I haven't worked with XML a whole lot, though, and when I do I'm generally very careful with my code so I won't end up having to go through too many errors... I suppose that's the best tip I can give! Also, use an editor that supports XML as a language to make it easier to spot errors pre-validation.

Comment: So when people say "this is an html5 compliant website" and it coughs up errors when you force it to parse it as xml (via **application/xhtml+xml**) then it simply is not html5 compliant, right?  The parsing engine will use it's "tag soup" version to render the page, which makes things like XSLT and namespacing unfeasible now that the "parsing intelligence" in trusting that the xml structure is clean is no longer there. I guess you could back off the `+xml` and allow the parser to take a Polyglot approach to your page, but not if it requires that kind of intelligence(?).

Comment: You *can* still serve HTML5 in an XML-serialized form. It's called XHTML5, and that's all there is to it - http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/xhtml5 As far as I've seen there are no differences between HTML5 and XHTML5 besides the syntactic rules imposed by XML.

Comment: So being HTML5 compliant does not equate to a MIME type of xhtml+xml.  XHTML5 does.  My issue is that in using a CMS, I am having a hard time finding (or knowing) if a template can be parsed as XML (because I need namespaces to work).